# SUM with multiple UNION queries

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, union

Is there a way to make a SUM out of multiple UNION queries? I have made UNION of multiple tables which returns a table with multiple rows, and each of these rows display a salary.

```
+-------------+--------+
| employee_ID | Salary |
+-----+-------+--------+
| 0001        | 630    |
| 0002        | 480    |
| 0003        | 600    |
| 0004        | 600    |
| 0005        | 600    |
+-----+----------------+
```

Is there a way to make a SUM out of all these rows (salaries) without creating a VIEW?
It would look like this:

```
    +-------------+--------+
    | employee_ID | Salary |
    +-----+-------+--------+
    | 0001        | 630    |
    | 0002        | 480    |
    | 0003        | 600    |
    | 0004        | 600    |
    | 0005        | 600    |
    |             | 2910   |
    +-----+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rollup`:

```
select employee_id, sum(salary) as salary
from (<your union query here>) x
group by employee_id with rollup;
```

Comment: Is `with rollup ansi` compliant?

Comment: @Andrew . . . I *think* so.  I'm pretty sure that `grouping sets` is ANSI and that is what I normally use (but MySQL does not support that).

Comment: I get nervous with anything related to grouping in MySQL, since it blissfully allows you to aggregate without group by.

Comment: Grouping sets are ANSI SQL, and there's also a <rollup list>, but a bit different from above.

Answer (score 0):

Well, ideally I would handle stuff like this in my presentation tool.  But based on your simple example:

```
select
employee_id,
sum(salary) as salary
from
<your table>
group by employee_id
UNION ALL
select
'' , -- or 'TOTAL' or whatever
sum(salary)
from
<your table>
```

Comment: yes but I have used different tables so I don't know what to put in the FROM part here:

Comment: select
'' , -- or 'TOTAL' or whatever
sum(salary)
from
<your table>

Comment: Gordon's solution will be easier in that case.